# Using Splunk - extract fields from xml data in a log file using xpath

Tags: xpath, splunk

I am using Splunk to extract a number of fields from xml data this is contained in a log file.  So to limit the search to be MOSTLY the xml file I start the search with this:
sourcetype="name of type here" "RULE"

This returns:

```
0123459 TripMessage.createMessage MsgSource <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tmsTrip xmlns="<link to trip" xmlns:ns2="link to common">
```

...

The file is very large.  This is part of it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tmsTrip xmlns="trip" xmlns:ns2="Common">
   <recordType>PURCHASEDLINEHAUL</recordType>
   <eventType>APPROVE</eventType>
.... more lines here that are not important
     <purchasedCost>
      <purchasedCostTripSegment>
         <purchCostReference>1587040</purchCostReference>
         <carrier information>
         <origin>
            <contact information>
         </origin>
```

This query selects the xml part text in the logging file and some of the fields are extracted and I can add to a table. (not including the source and sourcetype..)

```
| xmlkv | table purchCostReference, eventType, carrier, billingMethod
```

But need more fields that are child elements within the xml data. One of them is the **numberCode**. I am trying to use **xpath** to extract these additional fields.

```
| xmlkv | xpath
"//tmsTrip/purchasedCost/purchasedCostTripSegment/origin/ns2:numberCode" outfield=Origin | table purchCostReference, eventType, carrier, billingMethod, Origin
```

But no Origin data is returned when I add the field to the table.  There is no error.  The Origin column is empty.
[image]

**UPDATE**
I think the problem is that I need to add the **field** parameter.  The xml file is within a log text file.  I limit the search to get the xml file but not only the xml.  So I think xpath is struggling with the other text that is not xml.

**UPDATE**
I tried creating an extracted field using the wizard of the xml file that is within the logging statement.  The xml is huge and I can only select about 30% of it.  If anyone is good at regex, maybe they can give me some pointers as to how to complete the regex command to get all of the xml.  (I tried updating the props.conf file but do not have permission to add TRUNCATE = 0).
This is the xml file sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tmsTrip xmlns="trip" xmlns:ns2="Common">
   <recordType>PURCHASEDLINEHAUL</recordType>
   <eventType>APPROVE</eventType>
   <tripId>143642990</tripId>
   <legId>129014817</legId>
   <tripNumber>129014817</tripNumber>
   <tripLegNumber>1</tripLegNumber>
   <updatedDateGMT>2020-05-22T00:53:21.000Z</updatedDateGMT>
   <origin>
     <contact info>
   </origin>
   <destination>
     <contact info>
   </destination>
   <schedDispatchDateGMT>2020-05-22T13:00:00.000Z</schedDispatchDateGMT>
   <estimatedArrivalDateGMT>2020-05-26T06:00:00.000Z</estimatedArrivalDateGMT>
   <drop/>
   <hook/>
   <actualRoute>
     <info>
   </actualRoute>
   <standardRoute>
    <info>
   </standardRoute>
   <paidRoute>
     <info>
   </paidRoute>
   <settlement>
      <contact info>
               <ns2:daylightSavingsFlag>true</ns2:daylightSavingsFlag>
            </ns2:stopOffLocation>
         </stopOff>
         <schedDispatchDate>2020-05-22T05:00:00.000Z</schedDispatchDate>
         <estimatedArrivalDate>2020-05-26T01:00:00.000Z</estimatedArrivalDate>
         <billingMethod>LOCAL</billingMethod>
         <STCCCode>4711110</STCCCode>
         <planNumber>045</planNumber>
         <powerType>1X</powerType>
         <powerOnlyFlag>false</powerOnlyFlag>
      </purchasedCostTripSegment>
   </purchasedCost>
   <drivers/>
</tmsTrip>
```

This is how much the extracted field I can select:

<tmsTrip xmlns="trip" xmlns:ns2="Common">
PURCHASEDLINEHAUL

2020-05-22T00:53:21.000Z

This is the regex that Splunk creates to select the above xml

```
^[^\$\n]*\$\d+\.\w+\s+\w+\s+(?P<xmlMessage><\?\w+\s+\w+="\d+\.\d+"\s+\w+="\w+\-\d+"\?>\s+<\w+\s+\w+="\w+://\w+\.\w+\.\w+/\w+/\w+/\w+"\s+\w+:\w+="\w+://\w+\.\w+\.\w+/\w+/\w+/\w+">\s+<\w+>\w+</\w+>\s+<\w+>\w+</\w+>\s+<\w+>\d+</\w+>\s+<\w+>\d+</\w+>\s+<\w+>\d+</\w+>\s+<\w+>\d+</\w+>\s+<\w+>\d+\-\d+\-\d+\w+:\d+:\d+\.\d+\w+</\w+>\s+<\w+>\s+<\w+:\w+>\d+</\w+:\w+>\s+<\w+:\w+>\w+</\w+:\w+>\s+<\w+:\w+>\d+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+</\w+:\w+>\s+<\w+:\w+>\w+</\w+:\w+>\s+<\w+:\w+>\w+</\w+:\w+>\s+<\w+:\w+>\d+</\w+:\w+>\s+<\w+:\w+>\w+</\w+:\w+>\s+<\w+:\w+>\d+</\w+:\w+>\s+<\w+:\w+>\w+</\w+:\w+>\s+<\w+:\w+>\w+</\w+:\w+>)
```

So can I change the above regex to include the entire xml?

**UPDATE**
I tried extracting a field from the xmlMessage extracted field.  The xmlMessage field is above. I used the **xpath** command to extract **recordType**.  Put the result in a table. This is the command

```
| xmlkv | xpath field=xmlMessage
"//tmsTrip/recordType" outfield=Origin | table Origin
```

It returned no results.  This xpath command does not work for the simplest of queries.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Splunk, but it's possible the namespaced element (`ns2:numberCode`) is what's tripping it up. You could try this ugly workaround: `//tmsTrip/purchasedCost/purchasedCostTripSegment/origin/*[local-name() = 'numberCode']`

Comment: That still did not return any results.  I tried selecting one of the parent elements like "//tmsTrip/recordType" and it also does not return anything.  I don't know if Splunk has to be configured to use the xpath command also.

Comment: Thanks for trying...This is an xml file within a text file.  So I think this is specific to Splunk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to extract the data from the xml using **rex** and identify each instance of  the numberCode using **max_match** and **mvindex**
Here is an example of anyone who has this problem:

```
 rex max_match=0 "\<ns2\:numberCode\>(?P<location>[^\<]+)"| eval Segment1_Origin =  mvindex(location, 7)
```

The xml element is ns2:numberCode.  It is renamed to **location**. max_match=0 means unlimited number of instances.  The **mvindex** is zero based.  So the 8th instance of the location is set to the variable **Segment1_origin**

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of the event data, I can't say why the `xpath` command isn't working.

However, as a workaround, try the following instead of the `xmlkv` and `xpath` commands

```
| rex field=_raw "numberCode>(?<Origin>\d+)</"
```

This should work fine with mixed text and xml events

Comment: That did not work.  I tried creating an extracted field as the xml message. This xml file that is within the logging statement is huge and I can't select the entire xml file.  I tried  adding TRUNCATE = 0 to my local props.conf file but do not have permission to change it.  I should be able to create a regex statement to exact the xml but I am struggling with it.  I added to my original post above to show what Splunk created to extract the partial xml file.  If you are good at regex can you give me some pointers how to complete the regex command to get all of the xml?

Answer (score 0):

```
| xmlkv | spath path="tmsTrip.purchasedCost.purchasedCostTripSegment.origin.ns2:numberCode" output=Origin
```

Try `spath`